# Porting NetworkManager's system connections to another machine

Tags: networking, configuration, network-interface, networkmanager

I would like to transfer the "persistent" connections of NetworkManger to a new machine.
They are configured in the files that are found in `/etc/NetworkManger/system-connections/`.

I noticed that just copying files over does not always work.
It looks like some settings are machine-specific and need to be removed/reset.
I think that `interface-name` and `mac-address` need to be removed for the connections to work on a different machine.
Anything else?
What is the correct way to transfer the connection configurations to a different machine?

Comment: What kind of connections? I only have VPN connections in this directory and they can be copied as is.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I also have WiFi and Ethernet connections.

Comment: Linux servers are usually set up with fixed settings for the network(s). This makes the system not portable, you must tweak the system to make it connect when running in another computer. Typical Linux live systems and installed desktop systems, e.g. Ubuntu are portable, at least when no proprietary hardware driver must be used (for example for wifi). In other words, you need not do anything to make them connect to the network(s) when running in another computer. (There are also other things to consider, for example UEFI or legacy boot mode and graphics drivers, to make a system portable.)

Answer (score 0):

Copying the files is a suitable approach. Make sure that the files are owned by `root:root` and `chmod 600`.

After dropping a file, reload them from disk with `nmcli connection reload`.

---

Unfortunately, you may need to manually adjust profiles for the new system. If you tied a profile to a certain device, for example with `ethernet.mac-address` setting, then that profile will not work on another machine. In those case, the conflicting properties need to be adjusted.

Often it's good to prefer `connection.interface-name=` over `ethernet.mac-address=`, because the interface name is deemed to be more stable (though, even with predictable interface naming, it might be different on the new host).

In general, you don't need to tie the profile to a specific device. So you can also leave `ethernet.mac-address=` and `connection.interface-name=` properties unset. At least, if you anyway only have one physical interface on the new host.

Relevant properties that need adjustment are `connection.interface-name=`, `ethernet.mac-address=`, `wifi.mac-address=`, `match.*=`, `gsm.device-id=` (and maybe others).

Check `nmcli -o connection show $PROFILE` to see only the properties that are set for the profile. It will not show those that are set to the default, which is usually most of them. That can make it easier to see whether any properties need to be adjusted for the new host. Read `man nm-settings` for documentation about the properties.